# Trying to sort an array alphabetically

Tags: arrays, 2d, qsort

I'm trying to sort an 2d array alphabetically.

First of all I create an array an fill it with random user input, when pushing "0" the input stops an the program prints the original array. So far so good but now I'd like to sort this array alphabetically with qsort from library. Unfortunately i get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" from the Compiler.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 20

int compare (const void * a, const void * b ) {
    return strcmp(a, b);
}


int main(void) {
    printf("\n\nGeben Sie beliebig viele Vor- und Zunamen ein.\n");

    int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr)); 
    char name[MAX][MAX];
    char key[] = "0";   
    int i = 0;

    if (ptr != NULL) {
        do {                        
            i++;
            printf("Put in a first Name: ");
            scanf("%s", name[i]);
            printf("%s\n", name[i]);
        } while(strcmp(name[i], key) != 0);     // compare if input = 0.  -> if input zero then break
    }


    printf( "original input:\n" );
    for( int j = 1; j < i; ++j )
        printf( "%d: %s\n", i, name[j] );


    // Here is the probleme, I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" from Compiler
    qsort(name, i, 10*sizeof(name[0]), compare);
    for (int k =0; k<i; k++) {
        printf("%s\n",name[k]);
    }

    free(ptr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, any time you get a segmentation fault, the first thing to look at is manipulating points/arrays -- in C-like languages they're really the same thing.

Look at your use of `strcmp` and remember that is expecting a C string.  A C string is a null-terminated array.  Where is there going to be a null terminating your array `name` on the first pass through the program?

Answer: no one knows.  But if one doesn't happen along, `strcmp` will keep looking until it hits the end of the data segment, which causes, wait for it, a "segmentation fault".

Here's a couple of other questions:

1. What are you doing with the malloc'd pointer?  `int * ptr` will give you space for a pointer on its own.
2. Why are you bothering with `scanf` when `getch` will do the job?

Comment: ok, you mean i have to look for another method to get out of the do-while loop than "strcmp(name[i], key) != 0"

Comment: Yes.  Back up and think about what you want. name[i] is not a string -- it's just one cell.  you COULD compare it with '0', ie the CHARACTER '0'. But better yet, get clear on what you really mean to do -- before you write C code, "talk out" what you mean to do in English (oder auf DEutsch, moeglich.)

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

```
int i = 0;

if (ptr != NULL) {
  do {                        
    i++;
    printf("Put in a first Name: ");
    scanf("%s", name[i]);
    ...
  }
  ...
```

Notice that the first name will go into `name[1]`, and `name[0]` will remain uninitialized junk. Then `qsort` will pass (the pointer to) that junk to `compare`, which will pass it to `strcmp`.